# Sequelize adds a bunch of spaces at the end of the DataTypes.CHAR

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

My Store.ts file:

```js
import {DataTypes, Model, ModelAttributes} from "sequelize";

export default class Store extends Model {
  declare id: number
  declare name: string
  declare phone: string
}

export const StoreFields: ModelAttributes = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.CHAR,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  phone: {
    type: DataTypes.CHAR,
  }
}
```

My Item.ts file:

```js
import {DataTypes, Model, ModelAttributes} from "sequelize";

export default class Item extends Model {
  declare id: number
  declare name: string
  declare price: number
}

export const ItemFields: ModelAttributes = {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.CHAR,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  price: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  storeid: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'Store',
      key: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
  }
}
```

I'm initializing all these models like this:

```js
import {DataTypes, Model, ModelAttributes, ModelStatic, Sequelize} from "sequelize";
import Item, {ItemFields} from "./models/Item.js";
import Store, {StoreFields} from "./models/Store.js";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.PGURL, {dialect: "postgres"});

void Item.init(ItemFields, {sequelize, timestamps: false, tableName: 'item', modelName: 'item'}).sync()
void Store.init(StoreFields, {sequelize, timestamps: false, tableName: 'store', modelName: 'store'}).sync()

Store.hasMany(Item, {
  foreignKey: "storeid",
})
Item.belongsTo(Store, {
  foreignKey: "storeid",
})
```

Problem is, when I'm running `Store.create({name: "test", phone: "testphone"})`, sequelize saving this model name with bunch of spaces at the end

Sorry, I can't write spaces in md, so instead I pinned image from neon.tech dashboard query
[image: neon.tech query]

note that there are no closing quotes here in response.data.rows

Comment: Did you try `DataTypes.STRING` instead of `DataTypes.CHAR`?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, should have used VARCHAR (DataType.STRING), not CHAR, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I should've used VARCHAR (DataTypes.STRING), not CHAR, CHAR appends spaces to make sure that string length is 32767